# how to perform "scroll up" in nightwatch.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, nightwatch.js

I am trying to 'scroll up' for performing an e2e test. But any of the avaialble APIs are giving the the following error:

**Error while running .clickElement() protocol action: An unknown error has occurred – element click intercepted:**

After further troubleshooting I have found that if the page is having less number of entries, it is working fine.but it is faling if it needs to "scroll up" & then click the button.

The things I have already tried to perform the operation are as follows:

1. tried with moveToElement() & then click() & mouseButtonClick() but receiving the same error.
   this.waitForElementVisible("@selector")this.api.moveToElement("@selector",10,10).mouseButtonClick(0)

2.tried with separate JavaScript executer but its getting element is not clickable. Code Snippet:
this.api.execute(function (selector) {document.querySelector(selector).click();}, ['selector'])

please let me know is there any specific method/javascript executer method to perform scroll in nightwatch

Answer (score 0):

I use the `execute` method from the API then use the Window object and `scrollTo` method like so:

```
browser.execute(function(data) {
            window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        });
```

You can use the `getLocation` method from the API to get your specific elements x,y coordinates which are returned as a JSON object from that method, or you can hard-code your coordinates.  Here's the API link: [getLocation method documentation](https://nightwatchjs.org/api/commands/#getLocation)